# Distinguish different 'types' of nodes in the InstanceTree of the viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are running some processing on the contents of the InstanceTree, were the goal is to only collect the nodes which have a direct (geometric element) counterpart in the model -> meaning they are directly selectable by clicking on a model element in the viewer.

At first, it seemed like this was solved by focusing on the leaf nodes in the tree, traversing it recursively via `enumNodeChildren(node, callback, recursive)` and storing the node only if `getChildCount(dbId)` was 0, thus indicating we reached a leaf.

However, there seem to be constellations where there is geometry connected to non-leaf nodes as well as to their children. This seems to be the case where these nodes represent certain Revit Family Types with independent geometry.

We then tried to find a way to distinguish nodes with directly attached geometry vs. nodes which only act as "grouping" for real geometry nodes. But none of the API methods under https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Private/InstanceTree/ seem to help in this case (not even the promising `getNodeType(dbId)` as just returns 0 for all nodes involved).

A rather dirty fix for now is that we check for a id suffix in the node's name, which only seems to be present if there is directly related geometry. But I guess this also only just works if the viewable originates from a Revit file. [See this image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwBuo.png). It shows a parent node with no geometry, an intermediate node with geometry and several leaf nodes with geometry.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Tks for letting us know this issue - i am having a word with Engineering to see if they have any idea to get round this. Will let you know soon.

Comment: @BryanHuang thank you. Looking forward to hear from you

Comment: @BryanHuang Any updates on this?

Comment: Nope engineering has yet to provide any viable suggestions unfortunately I will continue the dialogue with them